# RSpec argument matcher for method that includes an optional parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method that has the following signature

```
def my_method(first, second = {})
```

Thus it can be invoked in two ways...

```
my_method 'first'
my_method 'first', { second: 'value' }
```

I'm only interested in testing the value of the first parameter in my tests and thus I'm trying to come up with an RSpec matcher statement that does the job. The closet I've got is

```
expect_any_instance_of(my_clazz).to receive(:my_method).with(code, anything).once
```

But this fails when I don't pass in a second parameter with the following error

```
     expected: ('first', anything)
          got: ('first')
```

I understand you can pass an arsenal of different matchers into the `with` method I can't find anything that will do the job of being optional in this way.

Can anybody offer an insight into how this could be achieved?

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/707) on the rspec tracker implies that there isn't a particularly easy way to do this at the moment

Comment: From that issue it looks like your right. Might have to watch and wait for that issues to get resolved. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
example do
  klass = Class.new

  expect_any_instance_of(klass).to receive(:my_method).at_least(:once) do |instance, arg_1, *|
    expect(arg_1).to eq('first')
  end

  instance = klass.new
  instance.my_method('first')
  instance.my_method('first', second: 'value')
end
```

Note, however, that we recommend that the `any_instance` features not be used: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance

Comment: No effect, same as before. I've just realised I'm using `expect_any_instance_of` instead is that makes any difference. Updated my question

Comment: Still breaks. Some to do with using a block truly breaks the tests direct afterwards. Guess I'll have to wait for the improved syntax

Comment: OK I've finally worked out what's going on. Adding a block here is replacing the implementation of my `my_method` so that it never returns the expected value. In my case `my_method` is a helper that populates a response body and instead of JSON it's simply returning `true` as the result of the `expect` call. Hence why my test breaks as Rack throws out this body as the wrong type. Any idea why it would be doing this?

Comment: I see there is an method `and_call_original` to invoke the original but how would I make this work with the block in your example?

Comment: I recommend you redesign your code so that it does not need such a brittle use of mocking to test it. Or test it with an integration test.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm limited by Rack::Test and Sinatra so I can't see another way to test this (all I'm trying to do is asset a helper is invoked with an argument, not that the helper returns any particular value. That's covered in another test). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
expect(my_instance).to receive(:my_method) do |first_param,other_param|
  expect(first_param).to eq(code)
end
```

That will give you a match on both cases.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using Sinatra and I'm getting the application cope being passed into `first_param' and the actual value being passing into `other_param` instead. If I fix that up, using this style appears to mess with the execution scope as code after this starts throwing errors.

Comment: Found another RSpec issue related to this but doesn't really have a working solution (that I can get working) https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/377

Comment: That's weird, I use this style of matching a lot and never saw it causing other side effects. Are you sure the matcher is causing issues here?

Comment: Definitely. I'm invoking a lambda attached to some of my examples after this and using the block somehow bricks it

Answer (score 0):

The avoid stub the response, you should add 'and_call_original' method:

```
expect(my_instance).to receive(:my_method) do |first_param,other_param|
  expect(first_param).to eq(code)
end.and_call_original
```